# numpy performace: custom elementwise operation in numpy over variable same size ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying to write an efficient vectorized numpy custom function that essentially performs elementwise mean sans -1 if at all present.

The idea is given list/tuple of same size ndarray as input produce a single same size ndarray which is effectively a (elementwise) mean of all ndarray provided as input.
The only possible values in these array can be [-1, 0, 1]. But when this custom mean is calculated, I want to ignore -1 from mean calculation if other values are present. The method for this custom mean `mean_with_dont_knows_int`.

I have tried universal functions and also operation along axis (after stacking the in arrays) but as the input shape increases, computational time increases reaching in minutes for relatively small `500, 500, 10` shape input.

Following is what I have got to so far:

```py
from typing import Tuple

import numpy as np
import pytest


def mean_with_dont_knows_int(*argv: int):
    arr = np.array(argv, dtype=np.int8)
    return mean_with_dont_knows_from_1d(arr)


def mean_with_dont_knows_from_1d(arr: np.ndarray) -> int:
    arr = np.delete(arr, np.argwhere(arr == -1))
    if arr.size == 0:
        return -1
    return int(arr.sum() / len(arr) >= 0.5)


def mean_with_dont_knows(*argv: np.ndarray, use_ufunc: bool = True):
    if use_ufunc:
        return np.frompyfunc(mean_with_dont_knows_int, len(argv), 1)(*argv)
    return np.apply_along_axis(mean_with_dont_knows_from_1d, -1, np.stack(argv, axis=-1))


@pytest.mark.parametrize("shape", [(10, 10, 5), (50, 50, 10), (500, 500, 10), (500, 500, 20), ])
def test_mean_with_ufunc(shape: Tuple[int, int, int]):
    mask1 = np.ones(shape, dtype=np.int8)
    mask2 = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.int8)
    mask3 = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.int8)
    expected = np.zeros(shape)
    expected[0, 0, :] = 1
    mask3[0, 0, :] = -1
    result = mean_with_dont_knows(mask1, mask2, mask3)
    assert np.array_equal(result, expected) is True


@pytest.mark.parametrize("shape", [(10, 10, 5), (50, 50, 10), (500, 500, 10), (500, 500, 20), ])
def test_mean_with_axis(shape: Tuple[int, int, int]):
    mask1 = np.ones(shape, dtype=np.int8)
    mask2 = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.int8)
    mask3 = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.int8)
    expected = np.zeros(shape)
    expected[0, 0, :] = 1
    mask3[0, 0, :] = -1
    result = mean_with_dont_knows(mask1, mask2, mask3, use_ufunc=False)
    assert np.array_equal(result, expected) is True
```

I am seeing performance bootlneck as the array size increases. Linear increase in performance actually .. as shown in the results below:

```
python -m pytest --durations=0  --capture=no  test.py                                                                              Exe on: 12:33:26 on 2020-08-16
=================================================================================================== test session starts ===================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/suneeta.mall/Documents/nearmap/data-science/planck
plugins: nbval-0.9.6, cov-2.10.0
collected 8 items

test.py ........

================================================================================================= slowest test durations ==================================================================================================
107.01s call     test.py::test_mean_with_axis[shape3]
104.04s call     test.py::test_mean_with_ufunc[shape3]
52.77s call     test.py::test_mean_with_axis[shape2]
52.32s call     test.py::test_mean_with_ufunc[shape2]
0.58s call     test.py::test_mean_with_ufunc[shape1]
0.54s call     test.py::test_mean_with_axis[shape1]
0.02s call     test.py::test_mean_with_ufunc[shape0]
0.01s call     test.py::test_mean_with_axis[shape0]
```

Obviously I am missing something that will explain why i spent 104.04s in doing simple mean over rather small array .. anyone has ideas/suggestions/improvements.

EDIT:

Have revised `mean_with_dont_knows` method based on @hpaulj's suggestion which seem to work fine on (500,500,10) shape arrays but with `(2000, 2000, 80)` shape I am back to looking at 55.5x seconds of compute time.

```
def mean_with_dont_knows(*argv: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    arr = np.stack(argv, axis=-1).astype(np.float)
    dont_know_mean = arr.mean(axis=-1).astype(np.int8)

    arr[arr == -1] = np.nan
    arr = np.nanmean(arr, axis=-1)
    arr = (arr >= .5).astype(np.int8)

    arr[dont_know_mean == -1] = -1
    return arr
```

Comment: Could you explain, may be even simplify the code and tests.  I spent a minute or so look at and don't have a clear idea of what you are testing.  Evidently the `ufunc` vs `axis` appraoch doesn't make much difference.  Neither `frompyfunc` or `apply_along_axis` are speed tools (ie. not true 'vectorizing').

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for looking into this. Really appreciate it. I have updated the description, hopefully it makes more sense now .. 
I admit that my approach is not quite right .. hoping I can get some guide here.

Answer (score 0):

I've streamlined `mean_with_dont_knows_from_1d` a bit:

```
def mean_1(arr):
    arr1 = arr[arr!=-1]    # simpler than np.delete
    n = arr1.size
    if n==0:
        return -1
    return int(arr1.mean() >= 0.5)
```

Applied with:

```
def foo(*argv):
    temp = np.stack(argv, axis=-1).reshape(-1, len(argv))
    res = np.reshape([mean_1(row) for row in temp], argv[0].shape)
    return res
```

With `reshape` I've simplified the 3d iteration to iteration over rows of a 2d array.

For `shape = (10,10,5)`

```
In [30]: np.array_equal(expected, foo(mask1,mask2,mask3))                                            
Out[30]: True
```

timing:

```
In [31]: timeit foo(mask1,mask2,mask3)                                                               
11.8 ms ± 184 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

compared with yours:

```
In [12]: timeit res = mean_with_dont_knows(mask1, mask2, mask3)                                      
29.5 ms ± 133 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [13]: timeit res1 = mean_with_dont_knows(mask1, mask2, mask3, use_ufunc=False)                    
31.3 ms ± 25.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Most of the improvement comes from the `mean_1` function.

```
def foo1(*argv):
    temp = np.stack(argv, axis=-1).astype(float)
    temp[temp==-1] = np.nan
    res = np.nanmean(args, axis=-1)
    return res >=.5
```

This takes advantage of `np.nanmean` one of a collection of functions that mask out `np.nan` values.  I probably could mask out `-1` directly, using ideas from `np.nanmean`, for now just use the existing code.  The speed improvement is substantial:

```
In [46]: np.array_equal(foo1(mask1,mask2,mask3), expected)                                           
Out[46]: True
In [47]: timeit foo1(mask1,mask2,mask3)                                                              
155 µs ± 217 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Basically I've avoided iteration 500 times (on a simple 3 element 'mean').

Comment: Thank you ... your insight into use of nan is quite handly.. I was thinking of converting -1 to 0 and doing similar prior but I was too down the rabit hole of ufunc thinking its vectorization and effficient
Have revised `mean_with_dont_knows` method based on suggestion which seem to work fine on (500,500,10) shape arrays with ETA `1.44s`  but with `(2000, 2000, 80)` shape I am back to looking at 55.5x seconds of compute time.